# Proving a given circle is not a retract of the Klein bottle -- is my solution correct?

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification, homotopy-theory, retraction

I am currently self-studying *Algebraic Topology: A First Course* by Greenberg and Harper.

I have "solved" the following exercise:

*Exercise*: Given the polygonal presentation $aba^{-1}b$ of the Klein bottle $K$, show that the circle $C$ given by $b$ is not a retract of $K$.

*My Solution:* Suppose for contradiction that $C$ is a retract of $K$. If we present $\pi_1(K) = \langle \alpha,\beta | \alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}\beta\rangle$, it follows that $\pi_1(C) \cong \langle \beta \rangle \subset \pi_1(K)$. To see normality, observe that $f : \pi_1(K) \to \pi_1(K)$ given by the rules $f(\beta) = 1$ and $f(\alpha) =\alpha$ is a well-defined group homomorphism with kernel $\langle \beta \rangle$, so in fact $\langle \beta \rangle \triangleleft \pi_1(K)$. By a previous exercise, it follows that $\pi_1(K) \cong \pi_1(C) \times \pi_1(K)/\pi_1(C)$; by the First Isomorphism Theorem, we know that $\pi_1(K)/\pi_1(C) \cong \text{im}(f) = \langle \alpha \rangle$, so in total we have:
$$\langle \alpha, \beta | \alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}\beta\rangle \cong \langle \beta \rangle \times \langle \alpha \rangle$$
which is false. $\square$

Is this solution correct? It makes sense to me, but I wanted a brief check.

EDIT: I have made a series of edits related to the labellings $\alpha,\beta, a,$ and $b$ as described in the comments below. The structure of the proof has not been changed.

Comment: Your notation is very confusing. Did you intend for $a$ and $\alpha$ to be different in some way? And for $b$ and $\beta$ to be different? And if not, how do you justify moving the $-1$ exponent around from the expression $abab^{-1}$ to the expression $\alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}\beta$?

Comment: The second one was a typo, which i have now fixed. The english letters are labels for the polygon presentation, while the greek letters are generators for the fundamental group. I felt that using the same letters would be confusing.

Comment: Well, okay, I can at least follow this now, but your post says nothing about "polygon presentation" so the confusion is still there.

Comment: I’ve edited again. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to the first edited version:** (regarding whether the $a$-circle is a retract)

Your proof does not work because your proof of normality of $\langle \alpha \rangle$ breaks down. The formula you give for evaluating $f$ on the generators of $\pi_1(K)$ does not extend to a homomorphism $f : \pi_1(K) \to \pi_1(K)$. The image of the relator $\alpha \beta \alpha^{-1} \beta$ is $1 \beta 1 \beta = \beta^2$ which is not a relator in $\pi_1(K)$, i.e. it does not represent the identity element of $\pi_1(K)$.

And in fact $\langle \alpha \rangle$ is *not* a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(K)$; the element $\beta \alpha \beta^{-1}$ is not an element of the cyclic subgroup $\langle \alpha \rangle$ (which can be verified by checking the usual injective representation from $\pi_1(K)$ into the group of isometries of the Euclidean plane).

**Answer to the second edited version:** (regarding whether the $b$-circle is a retract)

Okay, now it all looks correct!

Comment: I see the issue: when I edited the polygonal presentation as per your above comment, I messed up the notation and switched the role of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. I just fixed things up (in particular, $f$ is now well-defined since $f(\alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}\beta) = 1$), so how does the proof look now? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @William: If you've changed your question so that Lee's objection no longer applies (I haven't read your Q and Lee's A in any detail)—I'd advise against that. It tends to lead to confusion for future readers. It would be better, I think, to add your second attempt, rather than change the first attempt to a second. (This is a bit of a gray area, in that changes for clarity *are* good. So I leave it to your judgment!)

Comment: I agree regarding the gray area; in this case it was easy enough for me to lightly edit my answer.